# Suppose $A$ and $B$ are similar matrices. Show the following.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Please check my proofs

a) If $A$ is nonsingular, then so is $B$.

*Proof.* Suppose $A$ is nonsingular. Then $A^{-1}$ exists. Since $A$ and $B$ are similar, $B = S^{-1}AS$ for some nonsingular matrix $S$. Then

$$B(S^{-1}A^{-1}S) = (S^{-1}AS)(S^{-1}A^{-1}S) = S^{-1}ASS^{-1}A^{-1}S = I_{n}$$
$$(S^{-1}A^{-1}S)B = (S^{-1}A^{-1}S)(S^{-1}AS) = S^{-1}A^{-1}SS^{-1}AS = I_{n}$$

Thus $B^{-1} = S^{-1}A^{-1}S. \square$

b) If $A$ is nonsingular, then $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ are similar.

*Proof.* Following the proof of a), we deduce that $B^{-1} = S^{-1}A^{-1}S$, where $S$ is a nonsingular matrix. This implies that $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ are similar. $\square$

Comment: Your proofs are correct; well done.